# Why do I need to remove patches twice from my matplotlib Axes in order to remove them all?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `matplotlib` `Axes` object `self.a` defined on a `matplotlib` `canvas` object `self.fold_canvas`. During its construction, at some point I plot a bunch of transparent boxes on the plot, via

```
self.a.axvspan(bins[lower],bins[upper],color=palette[i],alpha=0.3, gid='foldstate')
```

Later, I want to get rid of them. I do this using the loop:

```
for p in self.a.patches:
    if p.get_gid() == 'foldstate':
        p.remove()
self.fold_canvas.draw()
```

For some reason, this loop removes all but one of the `axvspan` instances. If I then do it again, ie

```
for p in self.a.patches:
    if p.get_gid() == 'foldstate':
        p.remove()
for p in self.a.patches:
    if p.get_gid() == 'foldstate':
        p.remove()
self.fold_canvas.draw()
```

it works as intended, and all of the axvspans are removed.

Why do I need to do the loop twice to remove all of them?

EDIT: it appears that labelling them all with unique `gid` fixes the problem, so it may relate to an internal issue when multiple patches share the same `gid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this hasn't been touched: there seems to be an issue internal to matplotlib where `gid` needs to be unique for every labelled item. It seems to cause some silent failures if you reuse a `gid` anywhere.